# Silverlight Storyboard of DataTemplate

Tags: c#, silverlight, animation, storyboard

I'm working on Horizontal List, where each item gets expanded as you hover the mouse over it.

I have read few tutorials and I'm able to create simple animation with `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events however, it doesnt work in my datatemplate.

**ATTEMPT 1**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="StepBreadcrumbItem">
            <Border BorderBrush="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="60">
                <Border.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="100" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>

                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:1" Duration="0:0:0.5" To="60" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Border.Triggers>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text=" > " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Order, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='{}. '}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
```

**What am I missing?** It works fine for a single element. I get runtime error `Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2531

Category: ParserError

Message: Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.EventTrigger.RoutedEvent'.`

**ATTEMPT 2
I have now implemented it differently using MouseEnter event. Since attempt 1 failed.**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="StepBreadcrumbItem">
            <Border BorderBrush="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="60" MouseLeave="CollapseBreadcrumb" MouseEnter="ExpandBreadcrumb">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text=" > " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Order, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='{}. '}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

private void CollapseBreadcrumb(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var border = sender as Border;

            var duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);

            var sb = new Storyboard { Duration = duration };
            var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                Duration = duration,
                To = 50
            };
            sb.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);

            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath("(FrameworkElement.Width)"));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, border);

            sb.Begin();
        }

        private void ExpandBreadcrumb(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var border = sender as Border;

            var duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);

            var sb = new Storyboard {Duration = duration};
            var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
                Duration = duration,
                To = 100
            };

            sb.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);

            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath("(FrameworkElement.Width)"));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, border);

            sb.Begin();
        }
```

However, now it only expands when I have mouse over it, it stops when I do mouse leave and it doesn't run collapse. Also the reason why I set-up storyboard pro grammatically is because when I defined two storyboards and was just reassigning and running it to different item it looked very bad when I was moving my mouse across all list items.

Comment: are you sure it works for a single element? as far as i know Silverlight only supports Loaded EventTrigger.

Comment: For single element I actually use EventHandlers - `<Border BorderBrush="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="60" MouseEnter="Expand" MouseLeave="Collapse">`. Ill try changing it so it doesn't use EventTrigger.

Comment: that would be it, you can only use Loaded event trigger in Silverlight unfortunately, but I will show you a workaround as an answer

Comment: @Xin I had another attempt it is almost there - i can feel it... not fully there yet.

Comment: I've updated my answer again... with a simpler version. :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Silverlight only supports Loaded EventTrigger.

The workaround is pretty easy, use `Behaviors`. You just need to either use `ControlStoryboardAction` or `GoToStateAction` to trigger the animation.

Something like this,

```
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
            <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expression/archive/2010/02/22/switching-visual-states-easily-using-gotostateaction.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expression/archive/2010/05/25/control-storyboards-easily-using-behaviors.aspx) could be a good start. :)

**Update**

You better do this kind of animation in your xaml. Basically you need to create a visual state group that has two states, Normal and MouseOver. And then trigger them using GoToStateAction.

```
You would have something like this,
            <Border x:Name="border" Width="60" Background="Gray">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualTransition/>
                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <!-- your storyboard here -->
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                        <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="Normal"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                        <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="MouseOver"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**Update 2**

Actually you don't even need to create visual state group... Just use ControlStoryboardAction like this.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <Border x:Name="border" Width="60" Background="Gray" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Border.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Name="expand">
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.4" To="100" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="border" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
                <Storyboard x:Name="collapse">
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.4" To="60" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="border" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </Border.Resources>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                    <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource collapse}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                    <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource expand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <StackPanel Height="32" Width="26">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Order}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I have your solutions and I keep on getting `'ControlStoryboardAction' was not found because 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions' is an unknown namespace`. I do have Microsoft.Expression.Interactions and System.Windows.Interactivity referenced in my project. So i'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: that's weird, do you have Expression Blend installed?

Comment: Yup, EB 4. I used dll's from it. Yet same issue. Are there any other decencies or just those two?

Comment: no... i don't think so, how about you create a new porject from Blend 4, then in the Assets panel, type in ControlStoryboardAction and then just drag and drop it onto any of the controls and see if it complains?

Comment: @JustinXL Update 2, border resources: shouldn't it be x:Key rather than x:Name?

Comment: @Crono,that border is not a resource, it's within a data template resource.

Comment: @JustinXL Border isn't a resource but it does have a resource dictionary containing storyboards (expand/collapse) as resources. These storyboards should have keys, not names. Right?

Comment: Well, unlike WPF, you can actually have `x:Name` instead of x:Key in this case, and that's why the above sample code also works. See `In the Silverlight implementation of the resource dictionary concept, a ResourceDictionary can have x:Name instead of, or in addition to, an x:Key. If x:Key is not specified, x:Name is used as the key...` from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903952(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: @JustinXL ah, that's it, I'm using WPF not SL. Thanks for the info.